# looping through and making multiple figures of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

let us say I have a data frame of `df` and it's looping through 85 sets of the data frames and I want to make multiple figures of subplots of 4rows x 5 columns. So when I run the code I want 4 figures of 20 graphs in each figure and the last figure only containing 5 graphs. (The rest can be just empty graphs.) How can I achieve that? (in python)

Comment: The procedure you outlined in your questions seems like it would work. What are having trouble with? Dataframe filtering? Figure creation? Specific plotting commands?

Comment: The figure creatation and specific plotting commands